# pass variable to ejs file from express.js post request

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

After submitting a form I want to render the same page but with a 'message sent successfully' message above the form. With this code I get 'reference error, msg not defined', which I find strange as when I use the same code but in the GET request it works perfectly. Is there a different technique between GET and POST requests?

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/contact', (req, res) => {
    res.render('contact');
});

app.post('/send', (req, res) => {
    res.render('contact', {msg: 'Message sent successfully!'});
});
```

```html
<section class="section-b">
                <div>
                    <p><%= msg %></p>
                    <form action="send" id="contact-form" method="POST">
                        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
                        <input type="email" name="emailContact" placeholder="E-mail"><br>
                        <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="10" placeholder="Your message here..."></textarea><br>
                        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
 </section>
```

Comment: I have the same issue... I can not pass variable to ejs file from post request

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check if the variable (**msg**) is defined, in the `.get("/contact")` request you are not sending the **msg** as a parameter, so that's why you are getting the error

```
 <% if(typeof msg !== 'undefined') { %>
    <p><%= msg %></p>
 <% } %>
```

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Comment: Does this mean that we can register variable msg in the in `.get` request , and later we can use that variable in `.post` request , and practically we don't need to use `if(typeof msg !== 'undefined')` in `.ejs` file ?

Comment: if you render a view multiple times sometimes with variables and others without, you need to add a condition and check if that variable exist for each render

Comment: my knowledge is expanding :). Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

Conclusion based on @Chiller answer, if you don't want to use `<% if(typeof msg !== 'undefined') { %>` you need to define `msg` variable in the `.get` method, for example:

```
app.get('/contact', (req, res) => {
    res.render('contact', {msg: '')};
});

app.post('/send', (req, res) => {
    res.render('contact', {msg: 'Message sent successfully!'});
});
```

then, you can use `<p><%= msg %></p>` in your `.ejs` file without checking if variable is undefined.

But I prefer @Chiller answer as well.